# Message error its not showing using ajax via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to update data in a form via ajax with jQuery.

Im doing the update with sucess, but when I have empty fields Im not getting my error message saying: `myModal('config_datas_errempty','alert','Fill al fields please');`

And also if I write a wrong format for email I dont have any message too.

Do you see where might be the error? Because for me everyting seems fine and I already review the code many times!

**My php:**

```
 switch ($action)
    {
case 'data_update':

     $d['adress'] = $_POST['adress'];
     $d['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
     $d['fax'] =      $_POST['fax'];
     $d['email']=     $_POST['email'];

    if(in_array('',$d))
    {
        echo 'errempty';
    }
    else if(!valMail($d['email']))
    {
        echo 'erremail';
    }

     else
     {

        $updateData= $pdo->prepare("UPDATE config_data set adress=?, phone =?, fax=?, email=? WHERE id = ?"); 
        $updateData->bindValue(1, $d['adress']);  
        $updateData->bindValue(2, $d['phone']); 
        $updateData->bindValue(3, $d['fax']); 
        $updateData->bindValue(4, $d['email']); 
        $updateData->bindValue(5, '1'); 
        $updateData->execute(); 
     }
    break;
default: echo 'Error';
}
```

**My jQuery:**

```
 $('form[name="config_data"]').submit(function(){
    var forma = $(this);
    var data = $(this).serialize() + '&action=data_update';
    $.ajax({
        url:    url,
        data:   data,
        type:   'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
            forma.find('.load').fadeIn("fast");
        },
        success: function( datas ){
            if(datas == 'errempty'){
                myModal('config_datas_errempty','alert','Fill al fields please');
            }else if((datas == 'erremail')){
                myModal('config_datas_accept','accept','Sucess update');    
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            forma.find('.load').fadeOut("fast");
        }           
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: did you try `console.log(datas);`? what does it show?

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem now...I forget to put the break in the end of my case.